# PyQt signal with Twisted: Cannot catch custom signal

Tags: pyqt, twisted, signals-slots

Problem Description:

- A server process which keeps a database (Cacheable)
- A client which reads and displays the data in UI (RemoteCache)
- They talk to each other through Twisted PB
- I'd like to refresh my UI when the server database changes.

My client has a method, _*mutation*_handler, which is notified by the server
To notify my UI, I created a singleton Notifier class which emits a signal.
Then in my Qt widget, I wire the signal to the widget's slot.

```py
# inside the RemoteCache subclass on my client
# notified by the PB server when something happens
def __mutation_handler(self):
  notifier = Notifier()
  notifier.notify()

# inside notify.py
class Notifier(QObject):
  def __new__(cls):
    # Make it a singleton
  def notify(self):
    self.emit(SIGNAL('SomethingChanged'))

# inside the RemoteCache subclass on my client
def __mutation_handler(self):
  # singleton notifier
  notifier = Notifier()
  notifier.notify()
# inside my widget.py
class MyWidget(QWidget):
   def __init__(self):
     ... # code
     self.notifier = Notifier()
     self._create_signal_slot_connections()
     ... # more code
   def _create_signal_slot_connections(self):
     self.connect(self.notifier, SIGNAL('SomethingChanged'),self.shout)
   def shout(self):
     print 'Server's database changed!!!'
```

Problem:
  When I change something in my server's database, _*mutation*_handler gets called
correctly, then the signal is emitted alright. 
  However, MyWidget is NOT able to catch the signal.

Note: I am using qt4reactor to adapt Twisted's event loop to suit qt's

I really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't create a new Notifier instance every time `__mutation_handler` is called?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a new API for signals in PyQt4.  See http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html for examples on its use.  Perhaps this will work better.